# Replying to emails in Gmail with complete details of the original mail

Tags: gmail

When replying to emails in Outlook, the complete details of the original email are appended on bottom.

Ex:

```
From: Manas [mailto:****@****.com]
Sent: Wednesday, April 27, 2016 1:38 PM
To: Manas <****@****.com>
Subject: RE: Sample Email Reply
```

But when replying via Gmail web interface, only the original sender and time is appended with the message and a vertical bar.

Ex:

```
On 27 April 2016 at 14:55, Manas <****@****.com> wrote:
```

How to get all the details of the original email appended in Gmail when replying just like in Outlook and without the vertical bar as well?

Comment: Since you are replying to the original author of the email - why do you want to send him details he/she already has? Oh, and top-quoting is bad anyway.

Comment: @MartinSchröder That will be OK for 1 reply. When replying again and again to an email, all the details of the replied mails are buried within the thread, it becomes difficult to track which email was sent for whom. After all it boils down to individual requirement and may be violating best practices.

Comment: And replies are not always sent to original author. There are often circumstances when additional people may be copied to the reply.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you cannot. Every mail client has their own way of putting message details as part of the quoted reply. Some clients may allow you to change that.

There is no way to configure the Gmail web client to quote replies a different way. If you want to do that, you'll need to use a different client (such as Outlook).

Comment: My workaround for the moment is to hit forward instead, then copy the recipient email ids, remove the "forwarded" text and change "FW:" appended to subject as "Re:". Its painful, but works for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the Outlook way too. Maybe Gmail will one day give the choice...
Some time I add or delete someone. Change to a more appropriate subject.
The details provided by Outlook help the recipient to understand what happened.

It's easier (and very quick) to delete the details I don't want in outlook Rather than add them in Gmail (like Manas Woraround).